# How to add multiple X509v3 Subject Alternatve names during cerificate request (CSR generation) without editing openssl.cnf file

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl, certificate-authority, csr

I want to generate CSR for two domains. I have tried according to this http://apetec.com/support/GenerateSAN-CSR.htm   But there is no such section available in openssl.cnf file and i don't want to edit **openssl.cnf**
Also tried http://blog.endpoint.com/2014/10/openssl-csr-with-alternative-names-one.html but this generate error like this

**problems making Certificate Request
140391851812680:error:0D07A097:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_mbstring_ncopy:string too long:a_mbstr.c:154:maxsize=2**

Any Idea how to add two Subject Aleternative Name while generating Certificate request

Comment: Have you tried to set it up in the openssl.cnf to something like subjectAltName=$ENV::SAN and use environment variable SAN to set up its value?

Comment: But i don't want to edit openssl.cnf. If i edit openssl.cnf and add those two domain then in future if i need to generate csr for different domain then those domain which are in openssl.cnf automatically included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use a local config file

Just use a separate config file.

Then when you actually make the request tell OpenSSL to use the local config file with the `-config <filename>` parameter.

Like so:

```
openssl req -new -key example.key -config example-config.ini -out example.req
```

That way you don't have to edit the global config.

Also: I like to use the `.ini` file name extension for my OpenSSL config files, because that allows for nice doubleclickability and helpful syntax highlighting when you edit the file in a good text editor (like Notepad++). (And OpenSSL does not care about the extension, so ".ini" is what I will pick.)